# SlikSVN Command Line in PowerShell, Merging Multiple Revision Runs and Cherry Picked Reviisons

Tags: powershell, svn, command-line, merge, slik

I am using SlikSVN in PowerShell to automate merges. There are 4 possible scenarios in which a merge can be done, the first 3 I have the syntax sorted:

1. Cherry picked revisions only

   ```
   svn merge --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username LoginID --password Password --change '12,14,18' [URL_TO _BRANCH_TO_MERGE]
   ```
2. A run of revisions only

   ```
   svn merge --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username LoginID --password Password --revision '12:18' [URL_TO _BRANCH_TO_MERGE]
   ```
3. A mix of cherry picked revisions and a single run of revisions only

   ```
   svn merge --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username LoginID --password Password -c'12,14' -r'16:18' [URL_TO _BRANCH_TO_MERGE]
   ```

All of the above are working great. The scenario that I am struggling to get the syntax right and can't find any examples is where you have cherry picked revisions and multiple runs of revisions

I thought logically this would be how to do it:

```
svn merge --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username LoginID --password Password -c'12,14' -r'16:18,20:22' [URL_TO _BRANCH_TO_MERGE]
```

I got a syntax error (E205000), I've tried a few combinations but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this I found the answer to my question here:

[Is there any way to svn diff or svn merge across multiple non-sequential revisions at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692381/is-there-any-way-to-svn-diff-or-svn-merge-across-multiple-non-sequential-revisio)

You cna pass multiple -r flags e.g.

svn merge --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username LoginID --password Password -c '12,14' -r '16:18' -r 20:22' [URL_TO _BRANCH_TO_MERGE]